# Create a simple order list in 2010?

Tags: lookup-column

I am new to SharePoint 2010 but have some excel and access experience. I have a requirement to create an order list(List A) for storing products and quantities. The product field is a lookup column from a product list(List B). The product list also stores the price of the product. I need to create an order where the data from both the lists would be utilized. There is a calculated field in List A which would calculate the total which is [Quantity]* [ListB:product price] from ListB.

Here is what im trying to achieve. I need to create an order list (ListA) for a product and quantity. The product field would be a lookup field to a product in a product list (ListB), which also contains a product price for that product.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion but storing totals in a list or database table is bad design. And I don't think you'll be able to come up with a formula that will work. Just store the data as you have it, then you can use the REST Interface to query the information and display it.

SP 2010 REST Interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx

For further assistance, post the details of your lists and I'll formulate the query for you...